# Python printing a stringon two lines if string beginns with 'l'

Tags: python, string, text, output

so I have some code such as:

```
print(csv[0])
Genes = csv[0]
OutPut.write(Genes)
OutPut.write(',')
OutPut.write(csv[1])
OutPut.write(',')
try:     
    OutPut.write(csv[2])
except IndexError:
    print("No Lethality")
OutPut.write('\n')
```

Basically csv has 3 objects and they should print out as this:

atp,10101010,lethal

But for some reason, if csv[0] so the first value, begining with an 'l' it is printed as:

l

sfsf,1010101010,Lethal

I have tried using a for loop etc but I always get the same issue and all the other lines which start without an 'l' work perfectly.

Thanks

Comment: What does `print(','.join(csv))` print?

Comment: Seems to be the same thing - It works for everything else apart from the strings with l

Comment: Ah, if I print it it works fine, but if I output it to file it has the same problem

Comment: It seems to be any lines with special characters such as - or () are throwing the output off

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your description why you are seeing multiple lines, here's alternative logic that may help you diagnose the problem.
Try:

```
OutPut.write(','.join(csv))
OutPut.write('\n' if len(csv) == 3 else "No Lethality\n")
```

Or:

```
from __future__ import print_function
print(','.join(csv), file=Output)
```

Comment: Same issue, prints fine but outputs on separate lines if first string has a special character

Comment: What is the special character, I can't tell from your description.

Comment: Well so far it seems to be any strings with either a () or a - in them

Comment: I can't seem to replicate your issue, so hard to help beyond above. Can you share the input file.

Comment: Basically, I have two input files.   One is >>atp,1010101 and the other has >> atp,lethal. Now what I want to do is match the lethal from input one to the correct line using the first csv value in input file 2- Note: The matching has already been done, and I can print the lines to console perfectly, it is only when I output the value to file there is a problem.

Comment: Where are the special characters?

Comment: The special character is in the first csv, so where atp is. so for instance, atp can be l-()3gggs, etc

Comment: Sorry can't replicate your issue, so it might be logic elsewhere in your code. What is `OutPut` just a file object?

Comment: Yes just an outputfile handlername